# Separate values by day and night

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say i have a dataframe:

```
                         Bob       Ann
date                                  
2002-10-30 09:00:00      1.0       1.1
2002-10-30 10:00:00      5.5       3.4
2002-10-30 12:00:00      5.5       5.4
2002-10-30 14:00:00      4.4       3.4
2002-10-30 16:00:00      4.3       0.4
...                      ...       ...
2021-03-28 15:00:00      6.7       5.4
2021-03-28 16:00:00      6.5       4.8
2021-03-28 17:00:00      1.1       4.7
2021-03-28 18:00:00      6.7       4.8
2021-03-28 19:00:00      4.5       5.1
```

And i need to separate values from Bob and Ann by day (06:00 - 18:00) and night (18:01 - 05:59) in a boxplot (like this [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_boxplot.html) in seaborn, but for values in day and night), how do i make a third column for the "hue" data? Is it better to add a flag as a third column? or do something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some code to support the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use case for `df.between_time` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html#pandas.DataFrame.between_time)):

```
# Create example data

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(149)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2002-10-30 09:00:00', 
                                      '2002-11-01 09:00:00', 
                                      freq='2H'))
df['Bob'] = np.random.uniform(0, 5, size=len(df)).round(1)
df['Ann'] = np.random.uniform(0, 5, size=len(df)).round(1)


# Create a new column and label all rows as 'Night'
df['Time of Day'] = 'Night'

# Overwrite daytime rows with 'Day'. 
# df.between_time includes both start and end times by default
df.loc[df.between_time('06:00', '18:00').index, 'Time of Day'] = 'Day'

# Print result
df

                     Bob  Ann Time of Day
2002-10-30 09:00:00  4.4  3.0         Day
2002-10-30 11:00:00  4.9  1.0         Day
2002-10-30 13:00:00  4.3  1.3         Day
2002-10-30 15:00:00  4.2  4.7         Day
2002-10-30 17:00:00  4.5  3.6         Day
2002-10-30 19:00:00  4.3  3.6       Night
2002-10-30 21:00:00  2.4  1.5       Night
2002-10-30 23:00:00  2.2  0.4       Night
2002-10-31 01:00:00  3.0  2.8       Night
2002-10-31 03:00:00  0.3  3.5       Night
2002-10-31 05:00:00  2.1  1.5       Night
2002-10-31 07:00:00  4.5  3.6         Day
2002-10-31 09:00:00  0.6  2.3         Day
2002-10-31 11:00:00  4.6  0.2         Day
2002-10-31 13:00:00  1.0  4.3         Day
2002-10-31 15:00:00  0.8  1.2         Day
2002-10-31 17:00:00  4.8  3.2         Day
2002-10-31 19:00:00  4.9  2.5       Night
2002-10-31 21:00:00  3.8  0.4       Night
2002-10-31 23:00:00  4.5  3.3       Night
2002-11-01 01:00:00  2.9  0.6       Night
2002-11-01 03:00:00  4.3  4.3       Night
2002-11-01 05:00:00  0.6  5.0       Night
2002-11-01 07:00:00  4.5  0.3         Day
2002-11-01 09:00:00  3.0  1.1         Day
```